# Null pointer exception when using ItemizedOverlay with MapView

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I get the errors below when touching the mapview. The ItemizedOverlay is shown correctly, but I can not interact with it.  Been searching online for solutions but can't find any.

Logcat:

```
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemsAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:617)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.getItemAtLocation(ItemizedOverlay.java:586)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.handleMotionEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:498)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTouchEvent(ItemizedOverlay.java:572)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTouchEvent(OverlayBundle.java:63)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:643)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 21:32:47.278: E/AndroidRuntime(18467):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code that adds the itemizedoverlays:

```
// Add event markers
        List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        overlays.clear();
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlayCurrent , itemizedoverlayCompleted, itemizedoverlayFuture;
        GeoPoint point;

        // Add events
        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllEvents();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        itemizedoverlayCurrent = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        itemizedoverlayCompleted = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        itemizedoverlayFuture = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putLong(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_ID, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_ID)));
            point = new GeoPoint(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LAT)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_START_LONG)));
            CustomOverlayItem overlayitem = new CustomOverlayItem(point, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_TITLE)), null, CustomOverlayItem.EVENT_TYPE, b);

            if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE)) == EventDbAdapter.EVENT_TYPE_COMPLETED) itemizedoverlayCompleted.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            else if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE)) == EventDbAdapter.EVENT_TYPE_CURRENT) itemizedoverlayCurrent.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            else if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventDbAdapter.COLUMN_EVENTS_TYPE)) == EventDbAdapter.EVENT_TYPE_FUTURE) itemizedoverlayFuture.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        }
        overlays.add(itemizedoverlayCurrent);   
        overlays.add(itemizedoverlayCompleted); 
        overlays.add(itemizedoverlayFuture);    

        mapView.postInvalidate();
```

My itemizedoverlay class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));}

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {return mOverlays.get(i);}

    public int size() {return mOverlays.size();}

    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        if(size() > 0){
            CustomOverlayItem i = mOverlays.get(index);
            Bundle b = i.getBundle();

            switch(i.getType()){
            case CustomOverlayItem.EVENT_TYPE:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "EVENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case CustomOverlayItem.IMAGE_TYPE:
                break;
            case CustomOverlayItem.VIDEO_TYPE:
                break;
            case CustomOverlayItem.CONTACT_TYPE:
                break;
            case CustomOverlayItem.AUDIO_TYPE:
                break;  
            case CustomOverlayItem.UNKNOWN_TYPE:
                break;
            default:
                break;  
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: see line no .617 in ItemizedOverlay.java ?

Comment: Most NPEs can be tracked down by judicious use of the debugger. Put some break points at the start of your onTap for example and step through watching for nulls on i or b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem.  The error was arising when there was an itemizedoverlay, which had no overlayitems, on the mapview.  The following code solved the error:

```
if(itemizedoverlayCurrent.hasItems()) overlays.add(itemizedoverlayCurrent); 
if(itemizedoverlayCompleted.hasItems())overlays.add(itemizedoverlayCompleted);  
if(itemizedoverlayFuture.hasItems())overlays.add(itemizedoverlayFuture);
```

Comment: This helped!!

Found out that this is a known issue : [Android Issue 2035](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2035)

Comment: As I was not directly overriding the ItemizedOverlay class, I found out a similar fix worked for me: if (itemizedoverlayCurrent.size()>0)